# Responsive design of gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i want my grid to be responsive..
can you help me in that

I currently have the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../Js/gridviewScroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        gridviewScroll();
    });

    function gridviewScroll() {
        $('#<%=grvAssignStudentCource.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({  
            width:100,
            height: 200

    });
}
</script>
```

the above code i tried but its not responsive.

Comment: The code is obviously missing the CSS that would understand how you tried to make it responsive, having some javascript just changing the size without using any information from the windows size is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

use percentage value in the width, this results to fluid design.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        gridviewScroll();
    });

    function gridviewScroll() {
        $('#<%=grvAssignStudentCource.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({  
            width:100%,
            height: 200

    });
```

Comment: This is working but all thousand rows are coming together, there is no scroll bar for gridview

Comment: Add css property over-flow: scroll; and try.